# UITableViewCell frame margins in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to enter cell coordinates. When I apply the following code, the cell disappears from the application. How do I adjust the frame margin?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 25, bottom: 0, right: 25)
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false     
    }
```

Comment: What is the height of your cells? By default it's 44 and you set the bottom margin to 50.

Comment: I didn't define his height. I give 50 spaces from the bottom, but he's still not in that cell.

Comment: If you don't set the height then the height will be 44. Then why would you want a bottom margin that is taller than the entire cell?

Comment: I want 50 cells from the top. But it doesn't seem. Do I have to give you a height value? How do I give height value?

Comment: Do not edit your question with an answer. Post your solution as an actual answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cells, try this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
             willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,
      forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

But based on the edited information, it seems that you have margin in the container view of the table view. Either this comes from your constraints between table view and view (check them one by one) or you have layout margins in the view, in which case try;

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     // ... 
     self.view.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the row height to be the sum of the desired content height plus the desired margin height.

If all rows are the same height, set the `rowHeight` property of the table view to a number that is big enough for your needed content height plus the desired top and bottom margin.

If each row is a different height, then implement the `heightForRowAt` delegate method and return the needed total height (including margin).